# Print whole file tree (with depth) on server - FTP/PHP/Other?

Tags: php, ftp, terminal, hosting

Is there a way for me to print out a whole file tree from my hosting account so I can get a good view on where everything/file is?

I need depth down to the file level and most of the time my files are 3-4 folders deep.

Comment: Im almost looking for like a "tree" command for an FTP session.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo system('ls -oa -G -g  -s -S -Q -t "/home/userName/"');
?>
```